Support for CMakePresets version 6 in Visual Studio 2022
I am trying to use the outputJUnitFile in CMakePresets.json, an option which was introduced in CMakePresets version 6 (CMake >= 3.25), and with the video I found (referenced below) it seemingly should have been supported starting with VS 17.7, but I have VS 17.12.3 and the CMakePresets max supported version appears to still be 5.
This is my question:
Is the local schema installed by VS just outdated and the IDE does actually support CMakePresets up to the installed CMake version? Or does VS 2022 actually still only support up to version 5 of CMakePresets?
I can't find anything about the progression of CMakePresets support in VS2022, other than the Microsoft Learn documentation here which hasn't been updated since June 9th of 2023, and this video from the Pure Virtual C++ conference from April 24th of 2024.
Does anyone know if this is supported and I am missing something, or if this is something else like it was pushed to VS 2024 (or whatever the next version will be)?
I tried to do the following in my CMakePresets.json:
  "testPresets": [
    {
      "name": "vs-test",
      "configurePreset": "vs-with-test",
      "output": {
        "shortProgress": true,
        "verbosity": "verbose",
        "outputOnFailure": true,
        "outputJUnitFile": "${sourceDir}/out/test/vs-test/results.xml"
      },
      "execution": {
        "noTestsAction": "error",
        "stopOnFailure": false
      },
      "condition": {
        "type": "equals",
        "lhs": "${hostSystemName}",
        "rhs": "Windows"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "vs-nost-test",
      "configurePreset": "vs-nost-with-test",
      "inherits": "vs-test",
      "output": {
        "outputJUnitFile": "${sourceDir}/out/test/vs-nost-test/results.xml"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "vs64-test",
      "configurePreset": "vs64-with-test",
      "inherits": "vs-test",
      "output": {
        "outputJUnitFile": "${sourceDir}/out/test/vs64-test/results.xml"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "vs64-nost-test",
      "configurePreset": "vs64-nost-with-test",
      "inherits": "vs-nost-test",
      "output": {
        "outputJUnitFile": "${sourceDir}/out/test/vs64-nost-test/results.xml"
      }
    }
  ]

The version field in my CMakePresets.json file is set to 6 with the minimum required CMake version:
  "version": 6,
  "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
    "major": 3,
    "minor": 25,
    "patch": 0
  }

This results in errors in the Visual Studio 2022 Error List and causes VS to fall back to a default configuration. Each line number correlates with the line where outputJUnitFile exists in the section of the configuration file above.
Severity    Description                                 Project             File                            Line
Warning     Property name is not allowed by the schema  Miscellaneous Files Code\TestCPP\CMakePresets.json  375
Warning     Property name is not allowed by the schema  Miscellaneous Files Code\TestCPP\CMakePresets.json  392
Warning     Property name is not allowed by the schema  Miscellaneous Files Code\TestCPP\CMakePresets.json  400
Warning     Property name is not allowed by the schema  Miscellaneous Files Code\TestCPP\CMakePresets.json  408

Is this something I should file as a bug with the Visual Studio team?
Here is my local CMakePresets schema that is installed with Visual Studio 2022.

"This results in errors in the Visual Studio 2022 Error List" - Please, show that errors (add them to the question post).

Schema 6 was added in CMake 3.25. VS 2022 17.5 or later should have CMake 3.25 later. VS 2022 17.11 has CMake 3.29.

The JSON schema used by VS 2022 17.12.3 aligns with CMakePresets schema v 5 and causes parse errors that cause the processing of presets into command arguments to fail. The version of CMake used by VS 2022 is irrelevant if the CMakePresets integration does not recognize and generate the fields correctly. I am more than anything wondering if I manually update the supplied schema with v6 if it will break the integration or if the problem is just the older schema.

I have added the errors from the error list to the question.

If Visual Studio doesn't support a particular preset version, I would expect it to fail when it finds version key with unsupported version. Are you sure that your CMakePresets.json has "version": 6 key-value?

I added what I have set to the version field (the value is 6) to the question. I would expect the same thing.
